# Ruby on Rails 4. Change position of element in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Order and Part models which are associated as has_many:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :parts
end
```

And now i have order with 4 parts, for example, and i have to move first part in array to the third place.

In common arrays it looks like:

```
array.insert(2,array.delete_at(0))
```

But it doesn't work for associations:

```
order.parts(insert(2, order.parts.delete_at(0)) #error here
```

This code raises an error. How can i move entity in my association collection?

EDITED

My controller:

```
class PartsController < ApplicationController
  def reorder
    ...
    order_id = ...
    old_position = 0
    new_position = 2
    order = Order.find(order_id)
    parts = order.parts
    #now i have to move first part on third place. I hardcode it now but let's imagine that i have some algorithm
    parts[0].order_number = 2
    parts[1].order_number = 0
    parts[2].order_number = 1
    parts[3].order_number = 3

    PartService.new.process_parts (parts)

    order.save
  end
end
```

So my issue is that order.parts should be sorted according to order_number before i call PartService to process it. How can i sort my associations?

Comment: You might want to look at `acts_as_list`: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Answer (score 0):

Associations don't have a built in, predictable order.  It often changes based on the database changes.  You can't count on a particular order to stick around.

You'd need to add a position column, use that when you get the association (add a scope in the model maybe) and update that in code.

In your example, you can update each with `update_column` or `update_attribute`.  `update_column` will avoid triggering other callbacks.

```
...
parts[0].update_column(:order_number, 2)
parts[1].update_column(:order_number, 0)
parts[2].update_column(:order_number, 1)
parts[3].update_column(:order_number, 3)

PartService.new.process_parts (parts)       # this isn't changing anything, yet

order.save                                  # you won't need order.save
```

Comment: okey, and if i do this, how can i sort my associations according to position? I need changed data in my application before store (by default i load parts with has_many :parts, -> { order(order_number: :asc) }

Comment: You'd submit the order number for all the parts.  You can create a controller#action to change all the positions at once.  JQuery provides a drag and drop widget https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ (there are probably many others) that submits the json in the correct format for a rails action.

Comment: Yeah its okey, i have it. And now i need to reorder my parts on the server according to client request and then process result array before storing in DB. I can recalculate order_number for required parts, but how can i sort elements in array, because order is important on the next step of my app (i don't want to sort items manually). May be there is some function to sort elements of my array according to order_number?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but you can either add the order_number before save or update_column after save.  I think either way it would be in the controller in this case.  Is there a chance it can be submitted with the view?  array.sort_by will take an attribute.  And array.each_with_index will give you an integer to use to set order_number